# FakeItEasy - Mocking Function returns list<T> called by other function

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm new in tests' scope and i want to write test to this business logic's function using FakeItEasy.
In My `StudentsBusinessLogic` code i want to test the function `GetOldestStudent`.

- List item

Code:

```
public class StudentsBusinessLogic:IStudentsBusinessLogic
    {
        private IStudentRepository _studentRepository;

        public StudentsBusinessLogic()
        {
            this._studentRepository = new DalConcreteFactory().GetStudentsRepository();
        }

        //I want to test this function
         public Student GetOldestStudent()
        {
            var q1 = from students in this._studentRepository.AllStudents()
                         where students.Age >= ((from oldest in this._studentRepository.AllStudents()
                         select oldest.Age).Max())
                         select students;

            Student result = q1.First();
            Console.WriteLine(result.Age);

            return result;

        }
    }
```

Now, i have to mock that code snippet: `this._studentRepository.AllStudents()`,
because i don't like to use the `this._studentRepository.AllStudents()` (that uses the original db).
My question is: How to test `GetOldestStudent` with mocking `studentRepository.AllStudents()` call.
The test i have tried to write is:

```
[TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            // Arrange
            var fakeStuRep = A.Fake<IStudentRepository>();
            var fakeFactory = A.Fake<DalAbstractFactory>();

            A.CallTo(() => fakeStuRep.AllStudents()).Returns(new System.Collections.Generic.List<BE.Student> { new BE.Student { ID = 1, Age = 7 }, new BE.Student {ID = 2, Age = 55}});
            A.CallTo(() => fakeFactory.GetStudentsRepository()).Returns(null);

            // Act
            IStudentsBusinessLogic bl = new StudentsBusinessLogic(true);
            var res = bl.GetOldestStudent();

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(55, res.Age);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, that test leads to run-time exception due to problem in `IStudentRepository` ctor (specific issue that not related to this scope). But what i've tried to do is to skip on `IStudentRepository` initializing stage and Instead - to mocks it.
Can some one help me how to do it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to break the concrete dependency between your business logic class and the repository, example:

```
public class StudentsBusinessLogic:IStudentsBusinessLogic
{
    private IStudentRepository _studentRepository;

    public StudentsBusinessLogic(IStudentRepository studentRepository)
    {
        this._studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }
...
```

Now you can pass the mocked instance of the repository to your class:

```
var fakeStuRep = A.Fake<IStudentRepository>();

A.CallTo(() => fakeStuRep.AllStudents()).Returns(new System.Collections.Generic.List<BE.Student> { new BE.Student { ID = 1, Age = 7 }, new BE.Student {ID = 2, Age = 55}});

IStudentsBusinessLogic bl = new StudentsBusinessLogic(fakeStuRep);
var res = bl.GetOldestStudent();
```

Finally, you have your mock well defined, initialised and passed to the concrete class with the business logic.

This is one way to unit test your business logic class. You don't want (at least not now) to call the real repository or any concrete DAL implementation.

Note: your test should assert that the method from the mocked repository was called. FakeItEasy provide several ways to check that.

Comment: That works good. Thanks! Is there other way to do it? that mean i don't like to change my code (generally...) and that way i have to change/add ctor...

Comment: So, there are other ways. But breaking dependencies between your classes is a very good approach, I believe it is the cleaner way to unit test them. Otherwise you would need to hack this dependencies using static methods/factories, conditional service locators and etc...